# Shotgun returns ArgumentError since upgrade to ruby 3

Tags: ruby, sinatra, shotgun

I have upgraded to ruby 3 and since then, `shotgun` doesn't start with this error:

```
== Shotgun/Thin on http://127.0.0.1:9393/
/home/thb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:11:in `run': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/thb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9.2/bin/shotgun:156:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/thb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/shotgun:23:in `load'
    from /home/thb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/shotgun:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/thb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    from /home/thb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

Did anyone else run into this? Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

`shotgun` wasn't updated in the last four years. I would be very surprised if it supported Ruby 3.0.

And actually, there is a [PR open on GitHub](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun/pull/74) that fixes a deprecation warning in Ruby 2.7 that has not been merged for almost a year.

I would consider the `shotgun` gem being unmaintained and would look for alternatives. When you still need to use that gem then you should probably downgrade your Ruby version to the latest Ruby 2.6.6 version.

Comment: I saw that shotgun hadn't been maintained for a while, but couldn't find alternatives.